# Why the ouputs are different?

Tags: python

I have written the following code:

```
def control_list(string):
    if "Metallica" in string:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

but I found out that I get a different output when I run this code:

```
def control_list_2(*args):
    if "Metallica" in args:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For example, when I tried to run
`control_list("Metallica qaqaqaqaqa")`
the output is `True`

However, if I run
`control_list_2("Metallica qaqaqaqaqa")`
the output is `False`

Can someone explain me why?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: What does `print(repr(args))` display (and how is it different from `print(repr(string))`)? How does membership testing work in that type?

Comment: Try `if "Metallica" in args[0]:`

Comment: why do you *expect* them to be the same? What do you think `args` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*args` returns a tuple.
For example, in `control_list_2`, `args` would actually be `("Metallica qaqaqaqaqa",)`.

So when you try to do `"Metallica" in ("Metallica qaqaqaqaqa",)`, python does not see the exact string `"Metallica"` in that tuple.

If you are trying to see if any arguments contain the string, try:

```py
def control_list_2(*args):
    if any("Metallica" in item for item in args):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: well, a `tuple` technically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Atacan if this answers your question, consider marking it [as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @Monolith oh sorry, I'm new. I am getting started to learn how to use it.